# Alpha Vantage API not working for Brazilian stocks

Tags: stocks, brazil

I am trying to fetch Brazilian stock prices with [Alpha Vantage](https://www.alphavantage.co) API. For this example, I'll talk about PETR4.
I have used Alpha Vantage [Search Endpoint](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=PETR4&apikey=$). It returns the symbol of the currency:

> {
>       "bestMatches": [
>           {
>               "1. symbol": "PETR4.SAO", ...
>       } }

Nevertheless, the [TIME_SERIES_DAILY endpoint](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=PETR4.SAO&apikey=$) (or any other as a matter of fact) returns an error:

> "Error Message": "Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the
>   documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for
>   TIME_SERIES_DAILY."

Notice that it works [with GOOG ticker](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=GOOG&apikey=$), for example.

**What is the correct way to fetch prices of Brazilian stocks from Alpha Vantage API?**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I've edited the question and added it. I would like to know how to fetch the stock prices correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct symbol to Petrobras ON is PETR4.SA, you can try putting yours apikey at the and of the following request:

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=PETR4.SA&interval=5min&apikey= ***your api key goes here***

Comment: The symbol correction worked.